# OneDrive on mac doesn show all shared folders with me

Tags: macos, mac, finder, microsoft

On the website my account looks like this. There are 2 people sharing with me some files:

[image]

but after I have installed one drive on mac, I can see the following files:

[image]

A whole frolder from the second user is missing, and the second file (*tereny.xlsm*) from the first user is missed. Why?

On the website and on onedrive on mac, I am logged in as the same outlook account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only folders you have ‘can edit’ permission show in OneDrive desktop client.

You only have ‘can view’ permission to the missing folder, so that's why it's not shown.

[Add and sync shared folders to OneDrive](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-and-sync-shared-folders-to-OneDrive-8a63cd47-1526-4cd8-bd09-ee3f9bfc1504)

Comment: What if the folder-sharer needs me to view (only) the contents? Truly verklempt!

Answer (score 0):

If you still have issues seeing shared folders that you *can* edit, try adding them as shortcuts to the Files folder: you go to the Shared folder on the OneDrive web page and select one of the shared folders there, click the folder menu and choose "Create shortcut".

(Sorry, no screen shots, but my interface is in Swedish anyway...)